# Adding something to the start of a variable?

Tags: php

I am looking for some code that allows you to add +44 onto the beginning of my $string variable.

So the ending product would be:

`$string = 071111111111`

```
+44071111111111
```

Comment: `$string = '+44'.$string;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$string` variable isn't actually a string in this scenario; it's an integer. Make it a string by putting quotes around it:

```
$string = "071111111111"
```

Then you can use the `.` operator to append one string to another, so you could do this:

```
$string = "+44" . $string
```

Now `$string` is `+44071111111111`. You can read more about how to use the `.` (string concatenation operator) on the PHP documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Other people's suggestions of just keeping `$string` as an integer wouldn't work: `"+44" . 071111111111` is actually `+447669584457`. Due to the `0` at the start of the number, PHP converts it to an octal number rather than a decimal one.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine strings by .
$string = '+44'.$string;

Answer (score 1):

You can use universal code, which works with another parameters too.

```
<?php
$code = "+44";
$string = "071111111111";


function prepend(& $string, $code) {
    $test = substr_replace($string, $code, 0, 0);
    echo $test;
}
prepend($string, $code);

?>
```